# How do I hide the echo result from showing up on HTML?

Tags: php, html

For Instance consider this standard database connection php file.

db_conn.php

```
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "Yash123";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
echo "Connected successfully";
?>
```

If connected successfully it is shows that result onto the website.

What I'd need it to do is not show up on the html but be there in the file so I can test the file executing in the CLI(Command Line Interface) of PHP.

I am using require_once(); in the index file.

Comment: simple either remove that `echo` part or comment it

Comment: You want to hide "connected successfully" message?

Comment: uncomment it. or use php's `error_log('Connected Successfully');`. this would log that the connection was successful

Comment: @Mr.Gandhi I want to hide the connected successfully message from the html. Now if I execute this file in CLI of PHP it should show the connected successfully message.

Atikunde Thanks I'll try it in the CLI.

Comment: @Akintunde Thanks dude it worked like a charm, Can you write that as an Answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

uncomment the echo line. or use php's `error_log('Connected Successfully');`. this would log that the connection was successful. This would hide output from your html and log the string passed as parameter to your `error_log` file

Answer (score 0):

One could easily dispense with the echo statement and instead return the connection object upon success.  This would entail revising the OP code so that it becomes the contents of a database connect function. This idea I gleaned from [binpress.com](https://www.binpress.com/tutorial/using-php-with-mysql-the-right-way/17) and include suggestions from the Manual, too:

```
<?php

/* Assuming that user name,password and database name are   
   credentials that come from a file outside of the 
   document root for security. */

 function db_connect() {
   static $conn;
   $servername = "localhost";

   if ( !isset( $conn ) ) {

      // load and parse file containing credentials:
      $config = parse_ini_file('../config.ini'); 

      // Create connection
      $conn = new mysqli( $servername,   $config['username'],$config['password'],
    $config['dbname']);

      // Check connection
      if ($conn->connect_error) {
          die('Connect Error (' . $conn->connect_errno . ') '
                  . $conn->connect_error);
       }

       // Connected successfully
       return $conn;
  }
```

Comment: I see, a nice way to get the username and password of a Database from the configuration file of the DB system. I like the error_log because it serves the thing I required. I like this way of creating a DB too. I would only need to change the path to config file If I need to use it again.